# Где правильнее развернуть веб-сервис?

Tags: развертывание, веб-программирование, сервер

Скоро в продакшн выпускаю проект, в нем используются сторонние библиотеки, надо будет их ставить на сервере от имени администратора, вообще нужен будет административный доступ к файлам и пакетам (linux).

Что для этого подходит - облачный сервис или что-то другое?

Comment: @OlegUP Возможно, будет для Вас [полезным](http://hashcode.ru/questions/393312#393376)

Answer (score 1):

Просто ищите хостинг с ssh доступом. Желательно VPS. Под ваши нужды будет выделена абсолютно вся ОС со всеми правами. Тогда сможете там делать что угодно.

Comment: После того как все сделаю, помечу лучшим, то есть я на VPS смогу ставить пакеты rpm, например?

Comment: @OlegUP, да, но это зависит от того, какая ОС там будет стоять: CentOS, Debian и тд. На разных ОС разные расширения пакетов. А так у вас будет полный доступ к ОС сервера.